# How to convert wide format data to long format (Working with dates)?

Tags: r, tidyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe (measuring precipitation) where the days are along column heads.

```
Observations: 1,195
Variables: 33
$ Year  <int> 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 190...
$ Month <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
$ X1    <dbl> 9.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0....
$ X2    <dbl> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0...
$ X3    <dbl> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0....
$ X4    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ X5    <dbl> 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0....
$ X6    <dbl> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.3, 0.0, 0.0, 11.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0...
```

I want to convert it to long format where by days are also in one column.
I used:

```
library(tidyr)
long <- gather(dataframe, Day, PCP, -Month,-Year)
```

and the output is:

```
head(long)
  Year Month Day PCP
1 1901     1  X1 9.1
2 1901     2  X1 0.0
3 1901     3  X1 0.0
4 1901     4  X1 0.0
5 1901     5  X1 0.0
6 1901     6  X1 0.0
```

I want output to appear as below, where every month is associated with its days in sequence:

```
  Year Month Day PCP
1 1901     01  01 9.1
2 1901     01  02 0.0
3 1901     01  03 0.0
4 1901     01  04 0.0
5 1901     01  05 0.0
6 1901     01  06 0.0
```

So, how can i achieve this?
Your help would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Sort as you like, e.g. `library(dplyr); long %>% arrange(Year, Month, Day)`. You'll also probably want to remove the `X`s, e.g. by `mutate(Month = readr::parse_number(Month))`

Comment: Providing sample data in a copyable format is generally appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. You want to do two things

1. Remove the leading Xs from the day column (using `mutate(str_replace)`)
2. Sort so that the table is in month then day order. (using `arrange`)

This is achieved like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(
  year = rep(1901, 6),
  month = 1:6,
  X1 = c(9.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  X2 = rep(0, 6),
  X3 = rep(0, 6),
  X4 = rep(0, 6),
  X5 = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1.8, 0),
  X6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 4.3, 0)
)

tbl %>%
  gather(key = "day", value = "precip", X1:X6) %>%
  mutate(day = as.numeric(str_replace(day, "X", ""))) %>%
  arrange(year, month, day)
# A tibble: 36 x 4
    year month   day precip
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1901     1  1.00   9.10
 2  1901     1  2.00   0   
 3  1901     1  3.00   0   
 4  1901     1  4.00   0   
 5  1901     1  5.00   0   
 6  1901     1  6.00   0   
 7  1901     2  1.00   0   
 8  1901     2  2.00   0   
 9  1901     2  3.00   0   
10  1901     2  4.00   0   
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: It works, However the problem is it shows NAs for invalid days of the Months. eg. NA for April 31st and NAs for 1901-Feb 29, 30 and 31st days (which do not exist), and so it is repeated for rest of the Month in similar ways. I do not want to show those invalid days at all. I used:                  
    gather(key = "day", value = "precip", X1:X31) .                                        so how can this be rectified? I have 100 year data, manually removing NAs is cumbersome      
   1901  2  28  0.0
   1901  2  29  NA
   1901  2  30  NA
   1901  2  31  NA
   1901  3  1  0.0

Comment: You can probably just do `filter(!is.na(precip))` which would remove every row that has `NA` for `precip`. this is likely easiest if you have already run the code. You can also change `gather` to include `na.rm = TRUE`, since presumably there is an `NA` in your raw data for a day that doesn't exist.